# ancaught Error: Class 'testing\Person' not found

Tags: php, oop

I am learning Object-Oriended-Programming in PHP. And now I have a question about namespaces. I have index.php, classes folder and in this folder I have new folder named "Person". In Person folder is "Person.inc.php".

**index.php**

```
<?php
 include 'includes/autoloader.inc.php';
  ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf8">
 <title>Object Oriented Programming</title>
 </head>
 <body>


 
      <?php
    
      
     
     $person1 = new test\Person("Daniel", "Blue", 28);
     echo $person1->getDA();
     
     
     
     
     
     
 ?>
 
 
 
 </body>
  </html>
```

**Person.inc.php**

```
<?php

   namespace test;

 /*
class Person{
public $first = "Daniel";
private $last = "Nelson";
private $age = "28";  



  }

    class Pet extends Person {
   public function owner(){
  $a = $this->first;
  return $a;
   }
     }
     */


    class Person{
    //Properties
      private $name;
       
      public static $drinkingAge = 21;

    
 
    //Methods
    
    public function setName($name){
         $this->name = $name;
    }
    
    public function getDA(){
       return self::$drinkingAge;
    }
    
   
    
    
    }

    ?>
```

I do not understand what I can do, and when I delete namespace then everything is working fine and please help
please help me!!! thank you so much!!!!!!

**autoloader.inc.php**

```
<?php 
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader'); 
function myAutoLoader($className){
    $path = "classes/"; 
    $extension =".class.php"; 
    $fullPath = $path . $className . $extension; 
    if (!file_exists($fullPath)) { return false; } 
    include_once $fullPath; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Don't confuse namespaces with autoloading. Your use of namespaces is correct at first sight. Does `autoloader.inc.php` load the file that contains the class?

Comment: autoloader.inc.php is this :

Comment: <?php
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');

function myAutoLoader($className){
  $path = "classes/";
  $extension =".class.php";
  $fullPath = $path . $className . $extension;
  
  if (!file_exists($fullPath)) {
         return false; 
  }
  
  include_once $fullPath;
}
?>

Comment: Your file is `.inc.php` however your autoloader has `$extension =".class.php";`.